# Setting up new Apple ID, I keep getting message that password is not complex enough

Tags: itunes

I have chosen a password that has one upper case, lower case and 3 numbers,  but I still keep getting a message that it's not complex enough.  Why?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Apple's support site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201303)

> Strong passwords
>
> Apple policy requires you use strong passwords with your Apple ID. Your password must have a minimum of 8 characters, not contain more than 3 consecutive identical characters, and include a number, an uppercase letter, and a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the guidelines I found on Apple's website.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These are the [expanded requirements](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201303) from Apple:

- At least 1 letter
- At least 1 capital letter
- At least 1 number
- Cannot contain multiple identical consecutive characters
- Cannot be the same as the Apple ID account name
- A minimum of 8 characters
- Not a common password
- No reuse of old passwords for one year

Most people are tripped up by the *multiple identical consecutive characters* requirement and the last two requirements in the list. I'm not sure if Apple is also checking for use of all or part of your real name(s) from your account information in your password. Some password systems I've used enforce this additional requirement.

If you have too many passwords in your digital life, consider using a secure password manager like [LastPass](https://lastpass.com) or [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword).

`Disclaimer: satisfied personal and enterprise user of LastPass only.`